# Difference between these sentences

Tags: modal-verbs, subjunctives, present-subjunctive

a. The journalist demanded that the minister resigned.

b. The journalist demanded that the minister resign.

c. The journalist demanded that the minister should resign.

Is there any difference in meaning between above-mentioned sentences. All I know is the fact that it is a subjunctive construction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, see below

a. The journalist demanded that the minister resigned.

"resigned" Is past tense so cannot be correct. The resignation would be after the journalist's demand so should be "*the **M**inister resign".*

b. The journalist demanded that the **M**inister resign.

This sentence is correct and means what it says

c. The journalist demanded that the **M**inister should resign.

This sentence is an oxymoron Should is used to ask but demanded is used to insist (must).